# jquery ui resizable with draggable error

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I'm trying to have a div "child" be draggable and resizable inside a div "parent" and contained by it.
The problem is, when I resize my div child, it is blocked by something inside my div parent.
If you try to resize it's width to maximum you will understand.
If I delete the draggable option the problem disapears.

Here is a fiddle where you can see the problem:
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/circle73/34FPY/)

CSS

```
html, body, div { margin:0; padding:0; border:0; outline:0; font-size:100%; vertical-align:baseline; background:transparent; text-decoration:none; line-height:100%;}

.page_container{ width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; display: }
.main{ width: 800px; display: block; float: left; padding: 20px;}

.menu{ width: 200px; height: 700px; display: block; float: left; background-color: gray;}
.menu a{ color: black;}
.menu a:hover{ color: white;}

#parent{ width: 800px; height: 600px; display: block; border: solid 1px gray; padding: 0px;}
#child{ width: 100px; height: 100px;  display: block; border: solid 2px gray; cursor: move;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>Templates
        <li><a href="template_add.php">Criar Novo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Categoria</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Listar Templates</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>Slides
        <li><a href="#">Criar Novo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Categoria</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Listar Slides</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>Slideshows
        <li><a href="#">Criar Novo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Categoria</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Listar Slideshows</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="page_container">
    <?php include 'includes/menu.php' ?>
    <div class="main">
        <div id="parent">
            <div id="child"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(function() {
$( "#child" ).resizable({ containment: "#parent", maxHeight: 600, maxWidth: 800, minHeight: 10, minWidth: 10 });
$( "#child" ).draggable({ containment: "#parent", scroll: true });

});
```

If I delete my div "menu" the problem is solved but then, when I resize the with and height to maximum there is still a margin of 1px in the right corner and bottom.

Comment: change your CSS to `.menu {width: 200px; height: 400px;` and it is better, but what is the `display: }` doing in there?

Comment: Thank you @Mark Schultheiss, I've updated my jsfiddle. How can I remove the 1px margin in the right corner and bottom when I resize the width and heigth to maximum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your CSS and the float.  I commented the float out and it works fine.

```
.menu{ width: 200px; height: 700px; display: block; /*float: left;*/ background-color: gray;}
```

You could also let the height "auto-set" itself if you want the float. Is there a reason for the height to be 700px?

```
.menu{ width: 200px; /*height: 700px;*/ display: block; float: left; background-color: gray;}
```

also get rid of:

```
display:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alutz33/btrP3/

This link includes the new requests pertaining to the boarder problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/alutz33/rz4qw/

Comment: Thank you @alutz33, I removed all the display and float and it is running fine, but there is still a margin of 1px when I resize to maximum width and height. Do you have any ideas of what may be causing this?

Comment: check updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alutz33/rz4qw/  You don't need the `containment: "#parent"` and I changed the max size to reflect your border width.

Comment: I've checked but it remains the same as the first you linked in your post